# jQuery $(document).on() not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

My service, in general, uses jQuery 1.7.2.

I'm trying to handle an event in a jsp using:

```
    $(document).on("xyzEvent", function(){      
         console.log("xyzEvent completed");
         //some  more code
    });
```

There is no output.

But if I explicitly include jQuery version in my jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="abc.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
```

the above code also starts working. What could be the possible cause?

Comment: You need to add jquery to your page to run js function.

Comment: can you create the js fiddle and is that event is inside $(document).ready(function(){});???

Comment: did you get any **console error** when you did not mention explicitly?

Comment: who is triggering the event

Comment: You may have included two versions of jQuery. please check that.

Comment: No console error, and only 1 version is being used.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('body').on("click", function(){      
         console.log("xyzEvent completed");
         //some  more code
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7xd14gb7/

it is not advisible to register an event on document, try 'body' instead